# Chance that a random number from one set is higher than the random number from a different one

Tags: probability

Say I'm getting a random integer $x$ in the range of of values from $20\le x\le 120$. I roll a second number $y$ in the range of of values from  $50\le y\le 150$.

What's the probability that $x \gt y$?

Comment: I tried drawing these two sets and see how much they intersect but I fail to arrive at a proper equation.

Comment: Inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Both are inclusive.

Comment: Randon integer or number?

Comment: I presume it is an integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the square lattice $[20\,..120]\times[50\,..150]$ and count how many lattice points $(x,y)$ are favorable, i.e. satisfy $x>y$.

The favorable lattice points form the shape of a $45^\circ$ right triangle, hence their number is of the form $1+2+3+\ldots+N=N(N+1)/2$ for a certain $N$. Careful inspection of the figure tells you what the $N$ is. (It is $70$.)

Comment: Hm I did do it with different ranges to get a glance. https://i.imgur.com/SxtAnIJ.png 

Still not sure how to get a generic formula for any given ranges.

Comment: Thanks! The value of N constitutes the difference of the max value of the first set and the min value of the second one. So 120-50=70 in this case. Am I right?